# Изменение картинки при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите написать скрипт для того чтобы фоновая картинка при прокрутке становилась меньше и уходила в левую сторону.

Comment: Для того, чтобы вам помогли, выложите какой-то код или опишите подробнее вопрос. Чтобы это не выглядело как **СДЕЛАЙ ЗА МЕНЯ**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример реализации.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 $(".zoom img").css({
  transform: 'translate3d(-50%, -'+(scroll/100)+'%, 0) scale('+(100 + scroll/5)/100+')',
  //Blur suggestion from @janwagner: https://codepen.io/janwagner/ in comments
  //"-webkit-filter": "blur(" + (scroll/200) + "px)",
  //filter: "blur(" + (scroll/200) + "px)"
 });
});
```

```css
/* --- General Pen Styles --- */
body{
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 line-height: 2rem;
}
a{color: #000;}
h1{
 font-size: 2.6rem;
 line-height: 2.6rem;
}
.content{
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 90%;
 width: 720px;
}
main{
 padding: 1% 0;
 position: relative;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 box-shadow: 0px -10px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  height: 100%;
}
footer p{
 font-size: .8rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ccc;
}
footer a{color: #ccc;}
/* --- Important Pen Styles --- */

.zoom{
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-bottom: 55%;
}
.zoom img{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0%;
 left: 50%;
 max-width: 200%;
 width: 100%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 /* Thanks  @bastian_fiessinger. Use when activating blur effect:
 will-change: -webkit-filter, filter, transform; */
}
@media (max-width: 667px) {
 h1{
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  text-align: left;
 }
 .content{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
 }
 .zoom{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="zoom">
 <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/927610/pexels-photo-587409.jpeg">
</header>
<main role="main">
 <div class="content">
  <h1>Zoom Hero Image on Scroll</h1>
   <a href="http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/how-to-add-icon-fonts-to-any-element-with-css" alt="webdesignerwall.com" target="_blank">View Tutorial</a>
  <p>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
  <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>  
  <footer>
<p>A <a href="http://www.webdeisgnerwall.com" alt="web designer wall" target="_blank">webdesignerwall.com</a> Tutorial</p>
</footer>
 </div>
 
</main>
```

Разобрать пример подробнее можно на [webdesignerwall](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/zoom-hero-images-scroll)